# Save data from Javascript subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

I'm new to this. I want to get data from Rest API. Loading data from the endpoint is ok, but I want to use it later, outside the method. For example I want to sum one of the attributes of the todos in another function. In funcion loadTodos() the first console log shows the data, but the second one shows only "undefined". How can I save the values what loadTodos() gives back and use it later?

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { TodoDomainService } from '../services/todo-domain.service';
import { Todo } from 'app/model/todo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-listing',
  templateUrl: './todo-listing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-listing.component.scss']
})
export class TodoListingComponent implements OnInit {
  todo: Todo;

  constructor(private todoService: TodoDomainService, private router:Router) { }

  public todos;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadTodos();
    this.todo = new Todo();
  }

  private loadTodos() {
    this.todoService.getTodos().subscribe(
      data => { this.todos = data },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log("todos loaded." +this.todos)
    );
   console.log(this.todos)
  }
 }

private getSum(todos) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++){
    sum += todos.price[i]}
return this.aggregatedSales;
  }
```

Comment: add `console.log(data)` and watch Network tab in Chrome to monitor exact response.. if you can send me the outcome of these.. I may be able to help.

Comment: I've added three log points: two in loadTodos() function, one in the end of the ngOninit. The results:       
<1> second log in tha loadTodos(), this.todos value: undefined     <2>    
ngOninit log, value of this.todos: undefined         
<3> datasource loaded. (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "10014", amount: "40", date: "2018-10-02", industry: "IT", price: "9800", …}...

Comment: @AdriennKocsis, assuming `this.todoService.getTodos()` is an AJAX call, it's not correct to expect `this.todos` to have been initialised to the result of the latter call. That said, you should be able to use `this.todos` elsewhere provided the request completes itself, so what exactly are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I get the issue now.. your `console.log(this.todos)` will always show `null` because server request is still executing.. you need to add you logic inside  `data => { this.todos = data }` block.. hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`console.log("todos loaded." +this.todos)` will show a response because it is executed after the observable has completed.

`console.log(this.todos)` after your `.subscribe(...)` shows `undefined` because the observable hasn't yet finished, that is, the line `data => { this.todos = data }` hasn't been executed.

You are saving the data correctly for use. If you update your next called for the subscription to look like the following then the sum will execute:

```js
// from
data => { this.todos = data }

// to
data => {
  this.todos = data;
  this.getSum(this.todos);
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ffgb4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) of fetching a todos array and adding up the `userId` values into a `sum` variable then displaying the value.